# how many elements inside xpath nodeset

Tags: java, dom, matlab, xpath

I have this matlab function:

```
function trackName = getTrackName(xpath, gpxSourceDom)
    % Import the XPath classes
    import javax.xml.xpath.*

    % Compile the expression
    expression = xpath.compile('gpx/trk/name');

    % Apply the expression to the DOM.
    trackNames = expression.evaluate(gpxSourceDom, XPathConstants.NODESET);
end
```

I need a way to print every element inside `trackNames` NODESET. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick search of MATLAB and xpath returned this result:
[using xpath in matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31382-using-xpath-from-matlab/content/html/xpath.html)

The part you're missing is iterating through the results and displaying the name. For more ideas of what you can do with the nodes, check out the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html).

`for i = 1:nodeList.getLength
node = nodeList.item(i-1);
disp(char(node.getFirstChild.getNodeValue))
end`